# Oracle SQL Developer Error: Connection (CONNECTION_ID=CUJgpQYpQbOXdhiXCUyR3Q==) Vendor code 17002 Issue

Tags: oracle, error-handling, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am getting problem in connecting to my database in Oracle SQL Developer. Whenever I try to connect to my database, it gives me this error:

```
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=CUJgpQYpQbOXdhiXCUyR3Q==)

Vendor code 17002
```

Actually, I just use Oracle SQL developer to learn about queries running on a database. I have been using this database since a month but suddenly this error appeared now when I try to connect to the database directly or even manually. Please help me. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is the screenshot for further details:

[image: Screenshot]

I tried to do it through an SSH tunnel but stuck there also.

Comment: Including the connection information in the question might reveal an issue, though if that hasn't changed then something external has. I would guess you've used an IP address for the connection and that has changed. Is the database running on your PC or are you connecting to a remote DB someone else manages?

Comment: Hi. How can I check if the IP Address has changed for the connection? Is there any way to check so??

Comment: Also, I am running database on my laptop.

Comment: See how the connection is defined - right-click on it in the panel on the left and choose 'properties'. See if the hostname is a name or an IP address. As the DB is local, do `ifconfig` from a command prompt and find your current IP address. See if they match. If you're using DHCP then it's probably changed at some point, after a reboot or just if the lease wasn't renewed for some reason. Also see if the DB and listener services are running. They may be using your PC name, or could have the old IP, which will cause problems starting the listener and/or registering the database with it.

Comment: I changed my PC name a while ago and since then this issue has happened. I have now changed it back to the old name but error persists.

Comment: When I try to connect connection manually, it says "Status: Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The network adapter could not establish connection ...."

Comment: Have you rebooted since you changed the name back? it may be using stale values somewhere.

Comment: Yes I rebooted. Also, I checked one more thing while searching. The HostName of my sysDBA is localhost with port: 1521. When I check these in listener.ora and tnsnames.ora, then hostname is shown as my own name (that I changed last name as my pc name). Should I change the Hostname as  = localhost in listener.ora and tnsnames.ora or not?